# PHP encode json 3 in 1 response

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have in a file 3 json responses. I need to encode them in one Json with 3 Objects inside which are the three responses which I have separated. Any help?-

```
echo json_encode(array('result_temperatura'=>$output_result_temperatura));

echo json_encode(array('result_presion'=>$output_result_presion));

echo json_encode(array('result_altitud'=>$output_result_altitud));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build an array or object with the data:

```
$result = array('result_temperatura'=>$output_result_temperatura,
                'result_presion'=>$output_result_presion,
                'result_altitud'=>$output_result_altitud);

echo json_encode($result);
```

Or if you actually want a multidimensional array:

```
$result[] = array('result_temperatura'=>$output_result_temperatura);
$result[] = array('result_presion'=>$output_result_presion);
$result[] = array('result_altitud'=>$output_result_altitud);

echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine the array elements first,

```
$arr = array(
    'result_temperatura' => $output_result_temperatura,
    'result_presion' => $output_result_presion,
    'result_altitud' => $output_result_altitud
);
```

Then encode,

```
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, your answer works perfect but AbraCadaver gave me back a repply before. Anyway many thanks.